# The best way to ensure staticness in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, static

I've got this `Config`-class that I use in my PHP5 application to load & parse my static config. This far I've managed to keep the class from being a singleton/registry and instead passed the instance of the `Config` class around to wherever it's needed with the help of Dependency injection.

But now as I need to set/make changes in my `Config` during runtime at one place, my changes aren't reflected globally and being far from a specialist with the use of the `static` modifier in PHP, I need to ask:

What is the best way to ensure that changes to the properties in my `Config`-class are reflected throughout my application without making the class into a singleton? Can I just make the variable holding the config data `static`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This far I've managed to keep the class from being a singleton/registry and instead passed the instance of the Config class around to wherever it's needed with the help of Dependency injection.

If you pass the same instance of your `Config` class to every part of your application and you change a setting it should be reflected everywhere else.

In case you are creating multiple objects of the class (and parse that config file every time?!) you might want to stop doing that. It's possibly wasteful and I'd say it is confusing.

So if you [**`create only one`**](http://butunclebob.com/ArticleS.UncleBob.SingletonVsJustCreateOne) and pass that around everything should be fine.

---

Under the assumption that you create multiple instances of the object that only should exist once:

If you are able to "fix" your architecture to allow you to do that: Do so.

If you can't to that... well.. creating a **static property** to hold your values in a class that you can have **multiple instances** off is, at least in my book, a **major wtf factor**. If you can't fix (meaning it's to much off a hassle to do so) just "break" it in an expected way so other people don't trip over it.

I'd rather have a singleton than something that creates all the issues with singletons and **also** lies about being a wrapper for a global variable.

Comment: I think his emphasis was on avoiding singletons in the first place; much more fun reinventing the trees before even starting to reinvent the wheel instead of just being a productive member of society I guess...

Comment: @Blindy And "Create only one" is how one can avoid singletons for objects that only need to exists once for an application context. The issue with the singleton usually is it's global state and untestable (and so on, yada yada yada) and OP seems like he wants to avoid that.

Comment: Oh I see, interesting pattern. Kind of convention-ish, but I could see it working.

Comment: @Blindy Yes thats definitely convention over enforcement. Just as a developer can use reflection to create a second instance of a singleton we could create another instance of a DB connection. This just puts the "enforcement" into the 'framework' and out of that class so you have a nice separation of concerns. The neat thing about can be stuff like "now we need to run this peace of code two times in once request with different configs but config is a singleton, what now".

Comment: Bloody hell! I just had the biggest WTF moment this year. What happened was that I had set the variable containing my config params to `private` and overlooked it completely. Now it all works as expected. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

Blindly avoiding design patterns because you hear on Internet forums that they're bad is about as much an anti-pattern as singletons are in general. If a tool is right for a job, then it's right.

Look at your question, you're trying to *emulate singletons through a complex multi-update system* for God's sakes... And just so you know, making a class static is essentially turning it into a singleton, albeit an insecure one that can be overwritten at any time.

TL;DR: Think for yourself and use the right tools; make your config class a singleton.

Comment: Although the answer is blunt, a singleton is the right answer.

Comment: @Blindy I've tried to avoid singletons to ensure modularity and thereby making it easier to keep testability high, not because it's mentioned as an scary antipattern.

Comment: How would making the configuration variable `static` help with that?

Comment: I don't have the experience to answer that, unfortunately

Comment: Making a class static will hurt modularity and testability. Create an instance of the Config class and pass it around to everything that needs it, so that your approach is actually modular and testable.

Comment: @τεκ, of course that would make your modules more tightly coupled than they could be. It's all a game of trade-offs I guess.